Ag-Grid grouping Complex Objects
I need some help with Ag-grid grouping Complex Objects, I have an array of objects and I want to group by the main object name and then the child objects should be displayed in a different column, please see the image attached of what I'm trying to achieve, I using Angular 13.

[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "BMW",
    "models": [
        {
            "id": 5777,
            "name": "3 Series"
        },
        {
            "id": 5776,
            "name": "5 Series"
        },
        {
            "id": 5775,
            "name": "X5"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mercedes-Benz",
    "models": [
        {
            "id": 6777,
            "name": "C-Class"
        },
        {
            "id": 6776,
            "name": "E-Class"
        },
        {
            "id": 6775,
            "name": "GLE"
        }
    ]
}]

